Spring mail configuration for a SSL server
I have this connection to a SMTP server in my mail client, which works properly
Mozilla thunderbird config
I need to configure that in my java REST API using Spring JavaMailSender and I did like this
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getMailSender(SystemParameterService systemParameterService) {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        if (!(mailSender instanceof JavaMailSenderImpl))
            throw new MailSendException(translate("create_mail_service_error"));

        mailSender.setHost("webmail.xxx.yyy");
        mailSender.setPort(465);
        mailSender.setUsername("fest123@xxx.yyy");
        mailSender.setPassword("festpassword");

        Properties extraProperties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        extraProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        extraProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

        extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "5000");
        extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "3000");
        extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout", "5000");

        return mailSender;
    }

I got this error:
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: webmail.xxx.yyy
, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: webmail.xxx.yyy


How should I tune the properties to make it work? All the samples I see use gmail (port 587) or any other with starttls but none of them work for me

Are you running the program from the same system than Thunderbird?

Yes, same PC. I'm running the API in IntelliJ dev environment

I got a solution (trial & error). I post it here in case someone find it useful


@Bean
public JavaMailSender getMailSender(SystemParameterService systemParameterService) {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    if (!(mailSender instanceof JavaMailSenderImpl))
        throw new MailSendException(translate("create_mail_service_error"));

    MailPropertiesDto mailProperties = systemParameterService.getMailConfig();
    if (mailProperties == null)
        throw new MailSendException(translate("get_mail_properties_error"));

    mailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
    mailSender.setHost("webmail.xxx.yyy");
    mailSender.setPort(465);
    mailSender.setUsername("user@xxx.yyy");
    mailSender.setPassword("passwxxxyyy");

    Properties extraProperties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    extraProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "5000");
    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "3000");
    extraProperties.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout", "5000");

    return mailSender;
}


If you want to use SMTPS over SSL, then note what the JavaMail (and more modern Jakarta Mail) documentation has to say about this for the SMTP package. It states: if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*". Neither the question nor this answer takes this into account.
